# Scalaz use applicative builder with validations and a list of validations

Tags: scala, validation, scalaz

I'm working with Scalaz validations and I've run into a situation like this (note this is heavily simplified from my actual code, but the idea is the same)

Given:

```
case class Foo(bar: Int)

val x1: Validation[String, Foo] = Foo(1).success
val x2: Validation[String, Foo] = Foo(2).success
val x3: Validation[String, Foo] = Foo(3).success

val l1 = List(x1, x2)
```

I would like to be able to do something along the lines this:

```
(x3 |@| l1) { (x1, x2, x3) => /*do something with all of my Foo's*/ }
```

Of course if there were any errors, either in the list or outside of the list I'd like them to accumulate as they normally would.

I know the above syntax does not work, but any advice on how to achieve the result I'm looking for would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking, but you're aware that `l1.sequenceU` will give you a validation containing a list of `x1` and `x2`?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that. Just tried it and that does the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `List[F[A]]` and `F` has an applicative functor instance, you can turn the list inside out in effect with `sequenceU` to get a `F[List[A]]`:

```
scala> l1.sequenceU
res0: scalaz.Validation[String,List[Foo]] = Success(List(Foo(1), Foo(2)))
```

Or:

```
scala> (x3 |@| l1.sequenceU) {
  case (third, rest) => // do something with the values
}
```

It's also worth noting that if you find yourself writing things of the `xs.map(f).sequenceU`, you can use `xs.traverseU(f)` instead—it's exactly equivalent except you don't build an intermediate list.